# Error converting class pointer type to key

Tags: c++, class, pointers, key, stdmap

I'm a bit new to c++, and I'm running into a strange error. I have a fairly simple class I've written called `endpoint`. Within `endpoint`, I have an attribute of type `std::map<endpoint*, ppr_t>` (where `ppr_t` is a `typedef` for a struct). When I try to check for an item in the map by running the count method on the attribute, I get the following compile error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const endpoint*’ to ‘std::map<endpoint*, ppr_t>::key_type {aka endpoint*}’
```

I'm not sure why this error is popping up. Maybe it's because I have no comparison function for this class? Even so, the same error occurs when using `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the code that is causing the error, then we may be able to help fix it.

Comment: You can't cast a const pointer to a non-const pointer, that would defeat the purpose of constness.

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: share the code , then only anyone can provide certain answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a `const endpoint*` to `endpoint`, which discards const qualifier. This is made to prevent you from modifying the map's key value.

Maps are designed to find values fast by using their key. When you inserting a pair to a map you are "binding" a particular key with a value. For example, a phonebook. You remembers that you can call your friend (value = phone number) if you find his name(key) in the phonebook. But if you change his name, who is the owner of that phone number? This situation is strange and leads to errors. But instead, you can easily change your friends number, when he tell you that he bought a new phone.

So, you can use only const pointers if you get it from the key, not to brake the map's organization and still find values by their keys. And you can use non-const pointers or references to values, and change them any time you want, they will be still available with constant key.

Comment: This turned out to be the issue, didn't realize I couldn't use a const value to look up a map item. Thanks!

Comment: You can use const value to look up a map item. You cannot modify the actual key, stored in the map.